# Registro com coluna vazia afeta desempenho na hora da consulta

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, query

Digamos que eu tenho uma tabela com 4 colunas e 4 registros. Nem todas colunas são preenchidas na hora do formulário por não ser obrigatório, logo o banco de dados fica com algumas lacunas em sua grade! Exemplo:

```
ID | Item1 | Item2 | Item3
---------------------------
1  |  Dado |       | Dado
---------------------------
2  |       |       | Dado
---------------------------
3  |  Dado |  Dado | Dado
---------------------------
4  |       |  Dado | 
---------------------------
```

> Minha duvida é:
>
> > Esse "vazio" nos registros pode afetar o desempenho de alguma forma na hora da consulta ao banco de dados?

Comment: Em comparação a que? Eu sei, vai dizer com não ter esses "brancos", mas isso quer dizer pouca coisa. Minha tendência é dizer "só medindo" para saber, embora até dê para elaborar um pouco mais, mas a utilidade da informação será pequena. Ou seja, nesse caso específico está abstrato demais para cravar uma afirmação concreta :P

Comment: Basicamente o desempenho é mais afetado pelo volume de dados que a query vai resultar e consequentemente ter que trafegar entre o mysql até o php, do que o tempo em que o mysql vai demorar fazendo a busca dos dados em si (obviamente falando de querys não muito complexas).

Comment: Sendo somente um query de consulta simples, a perda e minima que ate para medir ficaria difícil. Mesmo sendo uma mais complexa e um banco enorme, seria minima a perda. Tenho tabelas com quase 200 mil registros em Sql server que e minimo a perda em relação a consulta de toda a tabela. imagina se for registro especifico.